# 'gyp' filed with exit code: 1 when trying to install zookeeper on window using npm

Tags: node.js, windows-7, npm, apache-zookeeper

I am try to install Zookeeper 3.4.5 on Windows 7 using npm 1.3.9.  When I enter

npm install zookeeper

I get

```
File "C:\Program Files\npm-1.3.9\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSProject.py", line 181, in AddFileConfig
raise ValueError('AddFileConfig: file "%s" not in project.' % path)
ValueError: AddFileConfig: file "." not in project.
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\npm-1.3.9\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:424:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\npm-1.3.9\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\Zookeeper-3.4.5\node_modules\zookeeper
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.17
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Same issue but the accepted solution didn't help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this has been a huge and annoying problem, that I have solved in many different (non-permanent ways), I FINALLY found the answer here:

[Error installing node-gyp on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155922/error-installing-node-gyp-on-ubuntu)

Since you are on Windows, try using a previous version of Python (for me it was using 2.6) for  Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [node-gyp installation](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation). It's works for me.

Was enough:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```