# npm install restify error on windows 7?

Tags: node.js, rest, npm, windows-7-x64

I am trying to build a REST Web Services using Node.js so downloaded and installed node.js version 0.10.29 from http://nodejs.org/ and python version 2.5 after installing that I tried to install restify.

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install restify
```

Its shows a **Error:'gyp' failed with the exit code :1?** as shown in the below image and I have also searched lot in google about this error but I couldn't able to find solution.

[image]

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155922/error-installing-node-gyp-on-ubuntu
It says You need python 2.6 during the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I have installed restify. The above error has been due to the conflict of the **python version 2.5** . When I installed **python version 2.6** it worked correctly. And also i have set system variables for microsoft sdk's.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I didn't have python installed, so installed latest 3.5.1 and it fixed the issue.