# spawn ENOENT error installing Zombie.js @contextify node-gyp rebuild Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, zombie.js, node-gyp, contextify

I'm trying to install Zombie.js on mac osx 10.9.5:

```
npm install zombie --save-dev
```

and am getting this error as a result:

```
Zacks-MacBook-Air:zackfischmann zackfischmann$ npm install zombie --save-dev

> ws@0.4.32 install /Users/zackfischmann/projects/zackfischmann/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


> contextify@0.1.9 install /Users/zackfischmann/projects/zackfischmann/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/zackfischmann/projects/zackfischmann/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.32
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "zombie" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v0.10.32
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! contextify@0.1.9 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.9 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/zackfischmann/projects/zackfischmann/npm-debug.log
```

I'm using:

```
npm 2.1.2
node 0.10.32
python 2.7.5
gcc 4.2.1
```

and I've set:

```
node-gyp --python /path/to/python2.7
npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7
```

Any suggestions as to what's going wrong and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the relevant part that goes wrong:

```
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

the spawn ENONENT means that some node script is trying to exec a file, but cannot find it. In this case its node-gyp.

Could it be that you have node-gyp globally installed or is gyp installed? I think this has conflicts with contextify

see [Error installing node-gyp on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155922/error-installing-node-gyp-on-ubuntu/23625291#23625291)